# HTML5 required message doesn't display on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, validation, firefox, required

I am developing a little wizard and to validate I use the required attribute. I am triggering the Validation like this:

```
if (jQuery('#generator_form')[0].checkValidity()) {
   nextStep();
}else{
   jQuery('#generator_form').find('#hiddenSubmit').click();
}
```

on Chrome this is working really well, but on Firefox the message is shortly shown but then disapears after 1 sec. Can anybody help with that problem?

best regards